# Unreal 4 compiled successfully but UE4Editor file doesn't exist

Tags: 20.04, compiling, executable, makefile

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on a desktop with an old i7 CPU and 16 GiB of RAM.

Here are the commands I ran to compile Unreal 4.27:

```
./Setup.sh
./GenerateProjectFiles.sh
make -j 4
make -j 4 ShaderCompileWorker
```

I had to try several times before the process completed. On previous attempts the machine ran out of memory and I had to do a hard shutdown.  It seemed to be the use of `make -j 4`, to try to limit the use of cores, that allowed it to finish.  I copied the full text of the compile readout in the terminal to a text file. The last bit was like this:

```
[86/105] Compile IPlatformFileSandboxWrapper.cpp
[87/105] Compile Module.VectorVM.gen.cpp
[88/105] Link (lld) libShaderCompileWorker-LauncherPlatform.so
[89/105] Compile Module.ShaderFormatOpenGL.cpp
[90/105] Compile Module.SlateFileDialogs.cpp
[91/105] Compile Module.VulkanShaderFormat.cpp
[72/72] UnrealBuildTool.exe CrashReportClient-Linux-Shipping.target
Total time in Local executor: 402.88 seconds
Total execution time: 789.38 seconds
[92/105] Link (lld) libShaderCompileWorker-VectorVM.so
[93/105] Compile Module.ShaderFormatVectorVM.cpp
[94/105] Link (lld) libShaderCompileWorker-DirectoryWatcher.so
[95/105] Link (lld) libShaderCompileWorker-SandboxFile.so
[96/105] Compile Module.ShaderCompileWorker.cpp
[97/105] Link (lld) libShaderCompileWorker-ShaderFormatOpenGL.so
[98/105] Link (lld) libShaderCompileWorker-Slate.so
[99/105] Link (lld) libShaderCompileWorker-ShaderFormatVectorVM.so
[100/105] Link (lld) libShaderCompileWorker-EditorStyle.so
[101/105] Link (lld) libShaderCompileWorker-TargetPlatform.so
[102/105] Link (lld) libShaderCompileWorker-SlateFileDialogs.so
[103/105] Link (lld) libShaderCompileWorker-VulkanShaderFormat.so
[104/105] Link (lld) ShaderCompileWorker
[105/105] UnrealBuildTool.exe ShaderCompileWorker.target
Total time in Local executor: 422.72 seconds
Total execution time: 809.24 seconds
kim@kim-MS-7917:~/3dDev/UnrealEngine-release$ make -j 4 ShaderCompileWorker
bash "/home/kim/3dDev/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Linux/Build.sh" ShaderCompileWorker Linux Development  
Fixing inconsistent case in filenames.
Setting up Mono
Running command : Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe ShaderCompileWorker Linux Development
Using 'git status' to determine working set for adaptive non-unity build (/home/kim/3dDev/UnrealEngine-release).
Target is up to date
Total execution time: 0.68 seconds
```

But, I go to the UnrealEngine/Engine/
Binaries/Linux folder and there is no executable there.

[image: Screenshot of Linux folder]

Possbily relevant?- I tried doing this in the cloned repo, and when that didn't work, I tried in a new folder with the files extracted from the zip download. In both cases, it spent over an hour fetching dependencies.

Any advice on how to get this to compile properly?

(Btw a friend successfully compiled Unreal using the same commands, except with make -j without the 4, and has been walking me through this, but now he's stumped.)

Comment: You have to add details. How did you obtained the sources? From where?

Comment: @N0rbert it was obtained from Unreal's Github repository, as is normal. We solved the issue, fortunately. Running `make -j UE4Editor` worked.

Comment: Had the same problem on Ubuntu 22.04. I also compiled with four parallel jobs and had no UE4Editor. So I decided to compile with just one job, by running `make` instead. In the docs it also says to use `make`- and it worked. After RequiredTools and UnrealFrontend were built, it started building UE4Editor (with 4 parallel jobs!).

Answer (score 2):

We fixed the issue by running `make -j 4 UE4Editor`.

My friend didn't have to compile UE4Editor separately, but he did have to do that for ShaderCompileWorker, thus he instructed me to do the same. He also is using Ubuntu 20.04.